# cider-jack-in: Symbol's function definition is void: clojure-project-dir

Tags: repl, clojure, cider

When I run `cider-jack-in` the following error appears. `Symbol's function definition is void: clojure-project-dir` I am very new to Emacs and this is totally stumping me. Let me know if you need more information and I will provide.

Comment: I'm fairly certain this has nothing to do with `evil-mode`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have clojure mode installed? Try `M-x install-package clojure-mode` if not and then run `cider-jack-in`.

Comment: I have since fixed the problem then forgotten what exactly I did to fix it. I remember it being something general like an installation was missing.

Comment: it's M-x package-install clojure-mode

Comment: fyi, had to delete clojure-mode from `rm -rf ~/.emacs.d/elpa/clojure-mode-*` then open emacs `M-x package-refresh contents` then `M-x package-install<enter>clojure-mode`